# Can you restore a ScyllaDB from only a backup of /var/lib/scylla/data folder?

Tags: scylladb

I had a single node scyllaDB which was lost, but only a backup of the `/var/lib/scylla/data` folder was done.

My question is, can a single node scylla be restored from only this backup? I already checked and the files don't contain any snapshots

Answer (score 2):

Is it a single node in a bigger cluster, or a one node "cluster"?

For the first, you might not need restore at all, just repair to sync with other nodes.

For the second, yes, for a single node, where token range distribution is not an issue, a backup of /var/lib/scylla/data will just work.
You still need to recreate the config files.

Answer (score 2):

All user data keyspace/s + system keyspaces (`system_auth`, `system_schema` and others) reside under `/var/lib/scylla/data`.

So if you have a backup of `/data` folder (with all it's subfolders -> tables, and sstables files etc.)
You should defenetly be able to restore your cluster with it's data.

You will need to recreate the cluster's `/var/lib/scylla/scylla.yaml`

The part about "no snapshots" is not clear...